# How can I center my <a> tag in my div?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to vertically and horizontally center my `<a>` tag in the div.

Here's what I have:

```
#button{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:27px;
    width:110px;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#6f97b6;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6f97b6, #3f729b);
}
#text{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:1em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and in my html file:

```
<div id="button">
    <a id="text">I am here!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: **This is not a duplicate** of the linked question- this relates to the OPs specific code. The answer in the linked question does not help here.

Comment: @SW4 Fair point. I've retracted my closing vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `line-height` to your `a` equals the height of your `button`.

```
#text{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:1em;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height: 27px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zj9tsfpc/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `height` on the parent to `line-height`.

This allows the `a`, which is inline content, to then be vertically centered to the middle which is its default behaviour by defining the (height) context to center it within. Without this, it is being centered according to the total height of the parent, inclusive of the top margin.

```css
#button {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 27px; /* <--- this */
  width: 110px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #6f97b6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6f97b6, #3f729b);
}
#text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <a id="text">I am here!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine in the code snippet, but on my page it does [this](http://gyazo.com/3d431e5ebdc2fda194b257ce03664b6f). What's going on?

Comment: @zachgates - its hard to say, can you replicate in jsfiddle? I cannot access your site

Comment: I fixed it by changing `line-height: 1em;` to `line-height: 27px;` in `#text`.

Comment: @zachgates - great. I have added some additional info as to why this is happening, which may help